# Find out rows of data frames which are not merged in merge()

Tags: r, dataframe

suppose I have two data frames and merge them using merge()

```
 df1=data.frame(X,Y,Z)
 df2=data.frame(X,Y,A)
 df=merge(df1,df2,by=c("X","Y"),all=F)
```

How to find out which rows of df1 and df2 are not considered in df?

Comment: Try `anti_join` from `library(dplyr)` or if you are looking at the row numbers , `row.names(df1)[!df1$X %in% df2$X]`

Comment: Actually cannot follow second option.. merging by two variales

Comment: Not able to reproduce the problem. All rows are included in my `df` . Can you share some sample data?

Comment: If you are looking for matching elements of 'X' from df1 with that from df2, we check the elements of X from df1 that are `%in%` df2 X column, and negating gives the elements that are not in df2 X.

Comment: the simpler way, while a bit "DIY" could be to add a variable "df1" from 1 to nrow(df1) in df1 and the same in df2, the those variables would give you the indices of each row that didn't go in df (you can later suppress the variables from df)

Comment: @ CathG it can be one of the ways .. thanks

Comment: @ akrun for a given value of X, there are multiple values of Y